# document.open() statement scroll the page automatically

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want to change the content of Iframe. but when I  use `document.open` in Iframe then my main page get scroll down bottom automatically.

```
 d.idoc.open('text/html', 'replace');
 d.idoc.write(text);
 d.idoc.close()
```

This issue is reproducible in safari and chrome mostly.

Answer (score -1):

First of you should take care of CORS Errors, because normally trying to get or change something within an iframe will be blocked by the browser duo same-origin policy.

if `idoc` is your iframe, do this:

```
idoc = idoc.contentWindow;
```

This should be the solution if you have no same-origin problems.

Also read this if you need further information: [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

*edit*

Regarding the comments, the question is something like: "Why is the page scrolling down?"

Current possibility: If the event got triggered within an `<a>`Tag and the Tag ahs a `#ID` in the `href`, the page will try to scroll to this position.

{edit follows after clearing facts with author - waiting for more input}

Comment: Loading page from same domain so no issue with Same Origin Policy.
Actually I am using IFRAME as HTML Text editor.

Comment: If you loading from the same domain, it shouldn't be a problem, but why you don't just include the Text Editor as is? Also did the `idoc.contentWindow` helped you?

Comment: do you know why page is getting auto scroll?? Please answer that question only.

Comment: Are you sure the auto scrolling coming from the script? Maybe some other  point is doing this change. If you using it as Text Editor, do you have something like `<a href="#" ..>` ? The # as href could do a scroll to the top.

Comment: So what is the reason for downvoting? I tested it and it's working for me, IF it's in the local domain, so the browser does not have Same Origin Policy. Don't just downvote and go on. Post what is wrong in your opinion and actually post a better solution. Nothing is more frustating than finding a post with the exact same problem, but instead of answers, there are only downvoted posts.

Comment: This is very rare behavior and I was expecting expert advise. You answers are no where near to my question.

Comment: You: `*scroll the page automatically*` | Me: `*do you have something like <a href="#" ..> ? The # as href could do a scroll to *`. | Add following to the current URL `#comment47484180_29625372` and the screen will scroll down. Also add a real question, you currently have only statements. I did what you wanted me to do: Fish the question out of the air or from my crystal sphere. Adding statements doesn't add a question. You trying to manipulate an iFrame, after a small research I found out that you need to use `.contentWindow`. My answer was expert level, your post wasn't. Please add a question

Comment: Also if it's not clear, my current question is: Do you trigger the open/write/close with an `<a>`-Tag which has a `href` something like `#ID` ? Ex. `<a href="#iframe">Change Iframe</a>` | Also please insert every code that is part of this. You can use the Snippet Function inside the Editor.